# Split a column in postgres in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with multiple employee id's with comma separation. Need to retrieve data with select query with where condition of that employee id's column but need to pass one id at a time. In the below employee id column have multiple id's.

```
SELECT lt.*  
FROM leave as lt 
WHERE true 
  and employee_id IN ($employee_id)
```

Comment: `$employee_id` also has comma separated data or just one id?

Answer (score 0):

So, try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id = ANY (string_to_array(ids,  ',')::integer[])
```